# how to make if statement non repetitious?

Tags: javascript

The following if statement is used within a `timeupdate` event, so it is called 3-4 times a second. While this method works just fine, I find it quite unattractive and I would like to get some hints towards making it a more simple solution without the repetition.

```
if (percent_watched >= 100) {
    while (i === 10) {
        console.log('video ended');
        i++;
        // Ajax Request
    }
} else if (percent_watched >= 90) {
    while (i === 9) {
        console.log('90% watched');
        i++;
        // Ajax Request
    }
} else if (percent_watched >= 80) {
    while (i === 8) {
        console.log('80% watched');
        i++;
        // Ajax Request
    }
} else if (percent_watched >= 70) {
    while (i === 7) {
        console.log('70% watched');
        i++;
        // Ajax Request
    }
} else if (percent_watched >= 60) {
    while (i === 6) {
        console.log('60% watched');
        i++;
        // Ajax Request
    }
} else if (percent_watched >= 50) {
    while (i === 5) {
        console.log('50% watched');
        i++;
        // Ajax Request
    }
} else if (percent_watched >= 40) {
    while (i === 4) {
        console.log('40% watched');
        i++;
        // Ajax Request
    }
} else if (percent_watched >= 30) {
    while (i === 3) {
        console.log('30% watched');
        i++;
        // Ajax Request
    }
} else if (percent_watched >= 20) {
    while (i === 2) {
        console.log('20% watched');
        i++;
        // Ajax Request
    }
} else if (percent_watched >= 10) {
    while (i === 1) {
        console.log('10% watched');
        i++;
        // Ajax Request
    }
}
```

Thanks for your sharing of knowledge :-)

Comment: Have you heard of a switch statement?

Comment: I have never used it as I am fairly new to JavaScript, but I will definitely take this a hint towards solving this.

Comment: Your use of `while` loops is certainly odd. The loop body will always be executed at most once (since you are modifying `i` inside the body). I recommend to read a JavaScript tutorial to get a better understand if the basic constructs: http://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html .

Comment: MDN is a good reasource, see [*switch*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Comment: @user45681. The switch statement would be as repetitious and verbose as the if-statement example shown by the OP. Since you still have to identify each possible condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking **while i === number** ? Are you sure this is the condition and as you incrementing i in the loop. ( this doesn't seem like valid logic)

how about :

```
var i = 0;
while (i <= percent_watched) {
  console.log(percent_watched + '% watched');
  i += 10;
  // Ajax Request
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a *switch* statement, however this seems to be just a matter of calculating an appropriate rounded value. Since the ajax request seems to always be required, call it after the "watched" logic:

```js
var percent_watched = 67;

if (percent_watched >= 100) {
  console.log('video ended');
} else {
  console.log(Math.floor(percent_watched/10) + '0% watched')
}
// Ajax Request
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are listening to the `timeupdate` event, can't you just get `currentTime` and then divide it by the total time? **EDIT** didn't see ajax request.

```
media.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(event) {
  console.log(media.currentTime/totalTime * 100 + '%')
  // do ajax request thing
}
```